Video Player Library for Compose Kotlin Multiplatform
I'm currently working on a project using Compose Multiplatform, and looking for ways to handle video player feature from a URL or local path. However, since ExoPlayer isn't supported for IOS side, I haven't found a solution. Has anyone integrated video player using a library or found other alternatives for Compose Multiplatform?

fyi - Recommendation questions are off-topic. Also, there's no programming question here. Please read [ask]

ok, you guys can remove the question then. @DavidMakogon

@DavidMakogon This is not off-topic. Pls refer what's Compose multi-platform. Its new technology for mobile apps by JetBrains.  He asked valid question.

@Ranjithkumar - it is indeed off-topic, as it's an open-ended question with no specific programming question, and requesting a recommendation. This is all covered in the docs around on-topic and off-topic questions. Also take a look at Why is "Can someone help me" not a useful question?.

@Ranjithkumar - as for [tag:compose-multiplatform]: that's a valid topic here, but that doesn't make the question valid, as (once again) there is no specific programming question.

@DavidMakogon, it is quite interesting that you insist on saying this is not a programming question, but the first answer to the question was provided with code? But anyway thanks.

@AhmetBurakIlhan - code in an answer doesn't make the question on-topic, as that code has no connection to anything you've written. Additionally, that answer links to that person's own product, with links to their product. I've already provided plenty of links that provide details for on-and off-topic questions, which you should consider reviewing. But, as written, your question is off-topic.

The stackoverflow community is so rude with the ability to dislike the question.
It is a helpful question and doesn't matter that it doesn't contain code.

I recently implemented a solution for playing videos in Compose Multiplatform that works for both Android and iOS. The library I used is called Compose Multiplatform Media Player.
Here are the steps to implement it:
First, add the dependency in your common module's build.gradle.kts file:
kotlinCopycommonMain.dependencies {
    implementation("network.chaintech:compose-multiplatform-media-player:1.0.22")
}

Then, you can use the VideoPlayerView in your composable like this:
import chaintech.videoplayer.ui.video.VideoPlayerView

@Composable
fun MyVideoPlayer(url: String) {
    VideoPlayerView(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            url = url
        )
}

that it's compatible with Android and iOS without needing platform-specific implementations.
Some advantages of using this library:
If you need to handle both images and videos, you can combine this with an image library like Kamel.
Github Compose Multiplatform Media Player
Github Kamel

fyi this can be considered spam, as you're promoting your own product. Also, the question is off-topic (it's a recommendation request, with no programming question)

You can build your video player using expect/actual functions without any third-party library. This article will explain how to develop that for both Android and IOS platforms.
creating-a-cross-platform-video-player-component-in-kotlin-multiplatform

fyi - link-only answers are not valid answers. Also, recommendation questions are expressly off-topic.
